# display text in different position when loading from a php to AIR app

Tags: php, actionscript-3, air

I've got a database with multiple lines of "title".

I asking my AS3 code to load theses lines like that :

```
urlReqSearchAll.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  
loader5.load(urlReqSearchAll);
loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,complete);
}

function complete(e:Event):void {
 addChild(list);
   products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
     products.reverse();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);
}
function showList():void {
    list.visible = true;
    searchList.visible = false;
}

function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {

    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 25
    myFormat.color = 0x000000;
    myFormat.font = "Mohave";
    listItem.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    listItem.text = item.title;
    listItem.x = 2;
    listItem.y = 75+ index * 40;
    listItem.width = 350;
    listItem.height = 80;

 listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        showDetails(item);
    });
    list.addChild(listItem);
    str = item.title;

}
```

The list is created in my textField `listItem`. But it's like that :

```
item1
item2
item3
..
```

Is it possible to display it like that ? :

```
item1                          item2                         item3

item4
```

If so, how ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming your "list" is a simple movie clip, you can do that following

You will have to declare x and y and then update them according to index and assign to the list item. for example:

```
var sx:Number = 0;
var sy:Number = 0;
var hgap:Number = 200;
var vgap:Number = 40;
```

then in your createListItem method

```
if( index%3 == 0 && index>0 )
{
    sx = 0;
    sy = sy+vgap;
}
else
{
    sx = sx + hgap
}

listItem.x = sx;
listItem.y = sy;
```

Hope this helps.